# Pinecone MaxRetryError and NewConnectionError

Tags: python, html, web-development-server, vector-database

An application I've hosted online throws an error whenever it tries to query a pinecone database that I've set up. Whenever I run the same code (same pinecone environment and API key) on my local device, the queries go through just fine. Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aamcdoc-fb22780.svc.northamerica-northeast1-gcp.pinecone.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /query (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd50980ce20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Edit: I found this on PythonAnywhere's Q&A (it's the service I'm using to host the web application) in regards to a similar question:
"It appears that you are not configuring your code to use the proxy on PythonAnywhere, so you cannot connect out from your free account. Have a look at the documentation for the library you're using to see how to configure it to use the proxy."

If that's the error, how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the library you're using to connect to the API?

Comment: @GilesThomas I looked through pinecone's documentation for its python client and couldn't find anything relevant :/ I could be looking for the wrong things, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the exact same thing. I just fixed it, also my first SO answer ever.

Using Python 3.10, pinecone-client you have to pass their proxy server during Pinecone init. Like this

```
from pinecone.core.client.configuration import Configuration as OpenApiConfiguration

    openapi_config = OpenApiConfiguration.get_default_copy()
    openapi_config.proxy = "http://proxy.server:3128"
    pinecone.init(
        api_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx",
        environment="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        openapi_config=openapi_config
    )
```